# Wrong direction of movement after changing node's velocity

Tags: 3d, game-physics, scenekit

After a node (car) collides into a "speed up" type of obstacle, it should speed up. Instead it slows down and starts moving out of the straight line. I checked if code is properly executed and it is, I assume the problem is with the coordinate system of the node or something of similar nature.

In `SceneKit`, y-axis represents the axis that point upwards and in my case, everything is happening on a plane with x-axis pointing in the direction of cars movement and z-axis for left/right direction of movement.

Before and after changing the velocity, I print out its velocity with this code:

```
print(car.physicsBody?.velocity)
car.physicsBody?.velocity.x += 0.2
print(car.physicsBody?.velocity)
```

The output is:

```
SCNVector3(x: 0.245669901, y: -0.120455861, z: 0.119086474) and
SCNVector3(x: 0.445669889, y: -0.120455861, z: 0.119086474).
```

So the car's x component does increase but does not cause him to move in the desired direction. As I said, the world's x-ray does point in the direction I want the car to continue moving. The car is also moving in the right direction before increasing the velocity.

I want to understand why does increasing car's velocity slow it down and why does it sometimes make it move in slight right/left as if the velocity vector is not applied in the same position as before.

I did try to apply a force at car's center before, with this code:

```
car.physicsBody?.applyForce(SCNVector3(0.2, 0, 0), at: car.presentation.position, asImpulse: true)
```

and this code (without applying at position):

```
car.physicsBody?.applyForce(SCNVector3(0.2, 0, 0), asImpulse: true),
```

but they both gave the car similar weird behaviors.

Am I doing something wrong? What else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with SceneKit. But if you add a value to a component of a vector without changing the other components then the direction of the vector changes.

If you want to make the vector longer by a certain factor without changing its direction you have to multiply all components by that factor.

Answer (score 0):

The velocity of the car decreases after colliding with the "speed up obstacle", because I forgot to turn off collisions between those two object. So with collision, the car lost some of its kinetic energy, causing him to slow down.